recenter-top-bottom does not work in elisp code
I have below code in init.el, it calls recenter-top-bottom to scroll the current line(at the middle of screen) to top. If I run C-L it works fine, but below does not move the line to the top of the window.
(defun show-results-block ()
  (interactive)
  "Run showk results"
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (other-window 1)
  (re-search-forward "#\\+RESULTS:" nil nil 1)
  (recenter-top-bottom) ; move current line to top
  (other-window 1))

(defun show-results-keys ()
  "define keys for 'show-results'."
  (interactive)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-x") 'show-results-block))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'show-results-keys)

Steps to reproduce:

Put above code in init.el.
write some org-babel code and run C-c C-c to generate results.
run C-c C-x to trigger above code, the RESULTS keyword in the middle screen of right side window. but I wish it scroll to the top of the window.


https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

The documentation for recenter-top-bottom indicates that by default it will center the current line in the buffer, not send it to the top:

Scroll the window so that current line is in the middle of the window.
Successive invocations scroll the window in a cyclical order to put
the current line at certain places within the window, as determined by
‘recenter-positions’.

You can see this by typing C-h f recenter-top-bottom <return>.
If recenter-top-bottom takes an optional argument. If you give it a number N, it will move the current line to N lines below the top of the buffer. You can use this to force the function to move the current line to the 0th line below the top:
(recenter-top-bottom 0)
This should give you the behaviour you're after.
You could also modify the value of the variable recenter-positions to make sure top is first in the list. Which approach you prefer will depend on how you use recenter-top-bottom in other contexts - i.e., if you change recenter-positions globally.

awesome, does C-l command send that parameter? I know khit C-l one time, it will be center, two time it will be top.

yes, but it uses some internal logic to check how many times it has been pressed in a row, and refers to the order specified in recenter-positions to set it.
